# Returning a '/n' character in c++

Tags: c++, newline

I am doing a homework assignment for my c++ class, and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are the directions:

Exercise: read02

Description

In this exercise, you will create a function to fetch a character from a string, but only if the specified index is in range. If it is out of range, return the newline character.

Function Name

read02

Parameters

```
str: a std::string
index: a size_t
```

Return Value

The char stored at index in str, unless index is out of range, then \n.

Examples

```
std::string data = "hello";
size_t i = 3;
char x = read02(data, i);
```

Hints

String Documentation
Remember to include the header file.
size_t requires the cstdlib header file.
size_t is unsigned (only includes values that are >= 0).
'\n' is the character constant for the newline character.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

char read02(std::string str, size_t index){
    size_t i;

    for( i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
        if(index > 0 && index < str.size()){
            return str[index];
        }
        else{
            return '/n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
error: multi-character character constant [-Werror=multichar]
             return '/n';
```

Any explanation as to why I'm getting this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Comment: The problem is that you didn't write the characters that the description told you to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply used the wrong slash for a new line.

```
return '\n'
```

This should work